# Django South - Creating initial migration for an app that has already populated tables

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

Scenario: I have an app in my Django application that I have never put under South management. I ran a syncdb a long time ago, and the models of this app have never had to change. Throughout time, I have obviously added data to those tables.

Now, I wish to put this app under south management, but once the tables already exist, I can create the migration file, but naturally, I cant execute them. I get a database error for existing tables:

`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1050, "Table 'ooyala_ooyalaitem' already exists")`

This is pretty obvious for me. What I was wondering is if there is a smart way to run the migrate command to use the current tables. I did not want to dump the data, delete tables manually, run the migration and repopulate things, and neither I wanted to create a data migration for this.

Any ideas on this? Is it even possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think the "freaking manual" is not well documented on this matter. A explanation in portuguese can be obtained here: http://django-na-pratica.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/iniciando-o-south-em-uma-base-ja.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This is covered in the manual](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app).

> Converting an app to use South is very easy:
>
> - Edit your settings.py and put ‘south’ into `INSTALLED_APPS` (assuming you’ve installed it to the right place)
> - Run `./manage.py syncdb` to load the South table into the database. Note that syncdb looks different now - South modifies it.
> - Run `./manage.py convert_to_south myapp` - South will automatically make and pretend to apply your first migration.
>
> Note that you’ll need to convert before you make any changes; South detects changes by comparing against the frozen state of the last migration, so it cannot detect changes from before you converted to using South.